# Where is /usr/local/? in the linux, there is no local folder

Tags: linux

I am using Linux and am looking for the  `/usr/local/` folder.

There is no local folder in the user folder.

How do I know where is /usr/local/?

- My Linux is CentOS 7.
- In python, they say some library files are not loaded from /usr/local/
  but in my user folder in GUI, there is no local folder so I'm confused about what exactly means `usr`. Python basic folder? or path folder?
  I'm 100% new to Linux.

Comment: A directory starting with a `/` does not reside in the user's `/home` directory. It is what it is `/usr/local/`

Comment: I believe `usr` stands for  "Unix System Resources"; there is no connection to any "user folder". What does `ls -d /usr/local` print for you? What does `ls /usr` print?

Comment: There should be a folder called `/usr/local`. It's not in `/home/user`. Run `ls -l /usr/local` and you'll see it. The command `echo $PATH` should also show `/usr/local/bin` as one of the directories.

Comment: It is unclear what it is you are asking and what it is your are expecting. Can you further explain what you mean by "user folder"?

Comment: You might post your distro and version in case it is something off-the-wall. But I can't imagine any Unix or Linux without /usr/local.

Comment: Oh, thanks for comment, I will edit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`usr` does not stand for user. The folder is actually located at `/usr/local/` you can try `cd /usr/local/`  to change your directory to it.